# Updating values in a list from a Tkinter entry box - Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to update the values in a list from values that are entered into an entry box created in TKinter. In my example the user enters the real name of the people in a list. Their real name will replace the 'x' in the example_list.

I have specified the variable as global in the method but the change only applies to the second value iterated in the list - the first is the initialised value - 99 in the code below.

I have also tried to specify a lambda function that updates i[1] individually, however this does not work - bad syntax. Besides the quit() function seems to be the only way to continue the iteration.

Is there a way to do this cleanly and with the first item in the list updated?

```
from Tkinter import *

example_list = [['Jimmy Bob','x','78'],[" Bobby Jim",'x','45'] ,["Sammy Jim Bob",'x','67'] ]        #Nickname/Real Name/Age 

newValue = 99

def replace():
    global newValue
    newValue = e1.get()
    print("Their real name is %s" %(e1.get()))
    #return(newValue)
    win.quit()

root = Tk()

for i in example_list:

        win = Toplevel(root)
        #win.lift()                                             
        e1 = Entry(win)
        e1.grid(row=1, column=0)

        var = StringVar()
        var.set(i[0])
        Label(win, textvariable = var).grid(row=0, column=0)

        Button(win, text='Enter Real Name', command=replace).grid(row=2, column=0, pady=4)
        #Button(win, text='Enter Real Name', command=lambda: i[1] =replace()).grid(row=2, column=0, pady=4)

        i[1] = newValue

        win.mainloop( )

 root.mainloop()

for i in example_list:
    print(i)
```

Comment: What in the world are you trying to do here? You're creating a new toplevel window and then quitting it? Why? If you're just trying to get input from a user, why not just use a tksimpledialog?

Comment: @WayneWerner Thank you. Too be honest I did not know this was an option. Spent hours looking for child windows for tkinter and toplevel was all I could find. Your solution solves all the problems I was having.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Wayne Werner who directed me towards the tksimpledialog, the solution to the problem is here.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkSimpleDialog

example_list = [['Jimmy Bob','x','78'],[" Bobby Jim",'x','45'] ,["Sammy Jim Bob",'x','67'] ]

root = Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
Label(root, text = "Enter the names in the dialog").grid(row=0, column=0)

for i in example_list:
    root.lower()
    i[1] = tkSimpleDialog.askstring('Enter their real name', 'What is %s real name' %i[0])
    print(i[1])


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure you don't need the root part - your `for` loop is enough and can stand on its own.

Comment: @WayneWerner Thanks, yes you are right, it is not needed, I was planning on using the root screen to add some more information but for this question it is unnecessary so I will make an edit.